# How to show user.name associated with timesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having issues with an app displaying the user.name in a timesheets index (shows all timesheets, not just current user timesheets)

User model:

```
# Table name: timesheets
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  starting   :datetime
#  ending     :datetime
#  approved   :boolean
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :timesheets
  ....
end
```

Timesheet model (standard user_id is the foreign key)

```
# Table name: timesheets
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  starting   :datetime 
#  ending     :datetime
#  approved   :boolean
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :starting, :ending
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :starting, presence: true
  validates :ending, presence: true
  validate :end_after_start
...
end
```

The index def from my timesheets controller:

```
def index
  @timesheets = Timesheet.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

and finally my index.html.erb file which has the user_id displayed, but I want the user name instead. Remember this is for an admin to approve the timesheets so it wont be the signed in user, but rather an admin who wants to see ALL the timesheets and approve the ones they want.

```
<ul class="timesheets">
<% @timesheets.each do |timesheet| %>
    <NOBR>
    <li>
          <%= timesheet.user_id %>
          <%= timesheet.starting.strftime("[ %^a %^b %e,  %Y - %l:%M %p ] - ") %><%= timesheet.ending.strftime("[ %^a %^b %e,  %Y - %l:%M %p ]") %> <%= (timesheet.ending - timesheet.starting)/3600 %> Hours
          <% if current_user.admin? %>
                |
              <% if timesheet.approved? %>
                 <%= link_to "Un-Approve", { action: :unapprove, id: timesheet.id }, method: :put %>
              <% else %>
                 <%= link_to "Approve", { action: :approve, id: timesheet.id }, method: :put %>
              <% end %> 
         <% end %>
        </li>
    </NOBR>
<% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Many thanks for any help, this is my first question asked so I hope I have followed all correct protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an association with the user model then you can get the user model by calling

```
timesheet.user
```

In this case of this problem

```
<ul class="timesheets">
<% @timesheets.each do |timesheet| %>
    <NOBR>
    <li>
          <%= timesheet.user.name %>
          <%= timesheet.starting.strftime("[ %^a %^b %e,  %Y - %l:%M %p ] - ") %><%= timesheet.ending.strftime("[ %^a %^b %e,  %Y - %l:%M %p ]") %> <%= (timesheet.ending - timesheet.starting)/3600 %> Hours
          <% if current_user.admin? %>
                |
              <% if timesheet.approved? %>
                 <%= link_to "Un-Approve", { action: :unapprove, id: timesheet.id }, method: :put %>
              <% else %>
                 <%= link_to "Approve", { action: :approve, id: timesheet.id }, method: :put %>
              <% end %> 
         <% end %>
        </li>
    </NOBR>
<% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly !!! I was trying timesheet_user.name and now feel stupid.

Answer (score 2):

As per the "***RAILS ANTIPATTERNS - Best Practice Ruby on Rails Refactoring***"

Ruby on Rails allows you to easily navigate between the relationships of objects and therefore makes it easy to dive deep within and across related objects. As per the Law of Demeter in Rails "use only one dot" during navigate between the relationships of object.
For example, **@category.product.name** breaks the Law of Demeter, but   @**category.product_name** does not.

So, the best way to get the user name for the timesheet, you should use

```
timesheet.user_name
```

Instead of

```
timesheet.user.name
```

For this just add the delegate method with the attribute you want to your Timesheet model as below

```
delegate :name, :email, to: :user, :prefix => true
```

So your Model will be

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :starting, :ending
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :starting, presence: true
  validates :ending, presence: true
  validate :end_after_start

  delegate :name, :email, to: :user, :prefix => true

  ...

end
```

Now, get the user name in your view file by calling

```
timesheet.user_name
```

And like this you can also get the user email as below

```
timesheet.user_email
```

Comment: Just so I understand this better why would one use the delegate functionality if the . notation works ? Is there a perhaps a security issue with doing it via . notation ?

Comment: No, you’re probably doing something more better and secure than the previous approach. And in previous approach you are violating the encapsulation. One of the key benefits of applying Law of Demeter is the low coupling via encapsulation.
For good explanation about the Law of Demeter please follow the blow link

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx